# Modify configProtectedData section in .config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, app-config

For the following:

```
<configProtectedData >
<providers>
  <clear />
  <add CertSubjectDistinguishedName="localhost" name="X509ProtectedConfigProvider" type="X509ProtectedConfig.X509ProtectedConfigProvider, X509ProtectedConfigProvider" />
</providers>
</configProtectedData>
```

how can i modify:

```
CertSubjectDistinguishedName="localhost"
```

and substitute "localhost" with something different?

I can't figure out how to read in "configProtectedData " section and modify it.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using XMLDocument:

```
    string path = Path.Combine(targetDirectory, applicationExecutableName);

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(path);

    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/configProtectedData/providers");

    node.InnerXml = string.Format("<add CertSubjectDistinguishedName=\"{0}\" CertStoreName=\"{1}\" name=\"X509ProtectedConfigProvider\" type=\"ProtectedConfigProvider.X509ProtectedConfigProvider, X509ProtectedConfigProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=098027505e2ed139\" />", certSubject, certStoreName);
    xmlDoc.Save(path);
```

If anyone knows a better way please post a sample. thanks

Comment: How can we generate PublicKeyToken for configProtectedData in Web.config?